# Deriving the Axiom of Infinity

Tags: set-theory, relations, axioms

I'm currently reading about recursion, working on various exercises since I haven't formally studied the material before. The main book that I'm following is Kunen's Set Theory book

There's an exercise which asks to derive the Infinity Axiom using a lemma. This lemma is as follows:

> **Lemma:** For a relation $R$ and a class A, if R is set-like on $A$, then $R^*$ is set-like on A.

His book defines $R^*$ as the transitive closure of $R$ on $A$, where $R$ is a relation and $A$ is a class. $R$ is *set-like* on $A$ iff $\{ x \in A : xRy\}$ is a set for all $y \in A$. The *transitive closure* $R^*$ is defined by $xR^*y$ iff there exists a path in $A$ from $x$ to $y$.

For the exercise, he provides a hint: let $A$ be the (possibly proper) class of all natural numbers and let $xRy$ iff $x = y + 1$.

**My Attempt**

I defined $A$ and $R$ as in the hint. Then, I considered $\{x \in A : xRy \} = \{x \in A : x = y + 1\}$. Since this is a set, $R$ is set-like. By the Lemma, $R^*$ is set-like, meaning that $\{x \in A : xR^*y \}$ is a set. I think $R^*$ would be the relation $x > y$. I'm guessing this would somehow lead to the fact that $\omega$ is set, which is equivalent to the Axiom of Infinity, but I'm just not seeing it.

Any help/hints with this exercise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that $R^*$ being set-like means that given $n$, $\{k\in\omega\mid k\mathrel{R^*}n\}$ is a set. What happens when you set $n=0$?

Comment: When $n=0$ then we have $\{k \in \omega : k R^* 0 \}$. If $R^*$ is the $>$ relation, like I assumed, then wouldn't we have $\{k \in \omega : k > 0\}$?

Comment: Yes, that what we would have. Knowing that this is a set, can you prove that $\omega$ is a set (i.e. that there is an inductive set)?

Comment: I'm not sure how to show $\omega$ is a set given the current set. For a set to be inductive, it would have to contain $\emptyset$ and for any $y$ in that set, $S(y)$ (the successor of $y$) would be in that set. There is a Theorem in the text stating that $\omega$ existing is equivalent to some limit ordinal existing, but I'm not sure how that would help us out.

Comment: What is missing from this set in order for it to be equal to $\omega$? Is $\omega$ inductive?

Comment: When the book defines inductive sets, they define $\omega$ as ``the smallest inductive set", assuming the Axiom of Infinity. Then, the Principle of Ordinary Induction is mentioned, saying that for any set $X \subset \omega$, if $X$ is inductive, then $X = \omega$. So, I see where you are getting at with asking if this set is inductive. Is this set missing $\emptyset$?

Comment: Yes. It only misses one element for it to be inductive. Note that inductive set need not be a set of integers.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense so far. So, it's missing one element for it to be inductive, which means that it can't be equal to $\omega$. What can we do from here?

Comment: C'mon, it can't be that hard to just show that you can add one more element to a set. Figure it out yourself! :)

Comment: Sorry about that. I always tend to make things harder than they need to be. I'm guessing I would use the Union Axiom to add the extra element to the set.

Comment: Asaf: Thanks for providing the hints and the "thinking steps". It helped a lot!

Comment: You're welcome!